# How to schedule remote mysql backups on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-xp, backup

I am looking for a smart way to take care of scheduling backups on a remote Mysql Unix/Linux server from my own personal Windows XP computer.

Is there any (free if possible, preferable of course) software that i can schedule that logs in to a mysql database and downloads a complete backup?

Would also need an alternative that might handle backups for databases that I don't have remote access to.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried MySQLBackupFTP (https://mysqlbackupftp.com/)? It's a great tool and we have really good experience with it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm supposing you have permission in your external host for these operations. That said, you have two approaches:

### Using the mysqldump of your Windows MySql installation and a bat script for scheduling

If you have wamp/lamp/etc installed on your windows machine, you can use mysqldump in a bat file and set windows scheduler to call it everyday at 0:00 AM.

Create a .bat file containing: (Make sure that your output directory is writable for this task in Win Vista and 7):

```
set DATET=%date:~-4%_%date:~7,2%
"c:\xampplite\mysql\bin\mysqldump" --host="YOUR_HOST" --user="YOUR_USER" --password="YOUR_PASSWORD" YOUR_DB > "c:\"backup_%DATET%_YOUR_DB.sql
pause
```

...and set a task in your windows scheduler to call this bat everyday.

If you need additional parameters to your backup, don't forget to check [mysqldump reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

### Using a "full-blown" software based backup solution

Check [Mysql's solution directory](http://solutions.mysql.com/solutions/tools?type=24). The only free solution I know of this list is the app from [topsoft](http://www.topsoft.ro/en/product_info.php/cPath/45/products_id/175/language/en) but I haven't tested it. You could check [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?words=mysql+backup&type_of_search=soft&pmode=0&words=mysql+backup&search=Search) as well.

Comment: Thanks, anyone got alternatives for what i can do where i only have on-server permissions for backup?

Comment: So, you only have access to your database from your application on-server, right? I would then backup my database to a directory on the server (like /home/user/backups), and download the backup files to my machine. Or if you want something more robust, check this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-web-server-files-to-a-ftp-server-automatically.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [pmbp](http://www.phpmybackuppro.net/)?

It's web-based (PHP) and among the other features, it lists:

- backup of one or several databases with or without data, table structure, ...
- three types of compression (no compression, gzip or zip)
- scheduled backups (by a small PHP script which must be included in an existing PHP script)
- interface for managment of the backups (viewing, restoring, downloading, deleting)
- backup directly onto FTP server and sending of backups by email
- platform independent - only webserver and PHP needed to run e.g. on MS Windows, Linux or Mac
- shell mode (to use manually or by cron script)
- backup of whole file directories (on a FTP server).
- backup databases from different accounts on several MySQL servers
- one installation can be used for all MySQL users of one MySQL server (used by webhosters)
- highest security through two alternative login methods (HTTP or HTML authentication)

Comment: Hi! That looks great. Tried to run it locally on a WAMP server, but it didn't work out to well. Is there any other choices available?

Answer (score -1):

I'm usually doing this from a Linux box, but you can do the same if you have Cygwin (or just the SSH executable) on your Windows machine:

```
ssh user@dbserver.com "mysqldump dbname | gzip -9" > localfile.sql.gz
```

Comment: @Win: In your solution, you haven't mentioned about the scheduling the backup.